# How can I set-up SQL Server alert for when table got corrupted?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Recently one of the database tables got corrupted in production's SQL server. I am trying to create an alert for this kind of issue. I don't see exact Error number or severity to choose from while creating alert.
How can I foresee or set and Alert in SQL Server for this kind of issue when they happen?
please help

Appreciate your responses.

Comment: How did you find out that "one of the database tables got corrupted"? Use the same logic.

Answer (score 2):

### for free

I [publish a script at my GitHub repository](https://github.com/erikdarlingdata/DarlingData/blob/main/Alerts/Alerts.sql) to set up alerts for high severity and corruption errors.

It assumes a couple things:

- You are using a version and edition of SQL Server that supports database mail
- You have the [CHECKSUM page verification option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/set-the-page-verify-database-option-to-checksum?view=sql-server-ver15) enabled on databases you care to get alerted about corruption in